# Is it an option to deploy specific schema with objects - procedures, funtions, views to multiples databases?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, ddl, pipelinedb

We have schema `utils` which we would like to deploy with database objects (procedures, functions, views) to multiple databases on different servers via Azure Devops Pipeline. Is there any option to treat this schema with objects as `ddl` file which will be attached to multiple database solutions ? Or we have to add manually all scripts to all database solutions ?

Comment: I added tags that I thought were missing, please edit if needed

Comment: So basically your question is "*how to efficiently deploy a schema of objects to different databases?*"? Would you be open to the idea of deploying them to a single database that all other databases can reference and still use?

Comment: Yes, but this schema have to be deployed on every database (not in separate new database)